# Django get child object through parent

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was trying to access the child object, through the parent object, as I want to perform different operations depending on the type of the object. What I have is:

```
#models.py
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(A):
    field1 = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class C(A):
    field2 = models.IntegerField(...)
```

I could perform 2 for loops and accomplish what I want:

```
for obj in B.objects.all():
    if field1 == 'something':
        do some operation

for obj in C.objects.all():
    if field2 == 5:
        do some other operation
```

But I was thinking, is it not possible to do this with 1 for loop and access the child through the parent?

```
for obj in A.objects.all():
    if obj.b and obj.b.field1 == 'something':
        do some operation
    elif obj.c and obj.c.field2 == 5:
        do some other operation
```

I also thought that [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) may do the trick, but it says it works only for `ForeignKey`.

Moreover, I was hoping to get this done, without using additional apps such as [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), because I feel like there should be a simple query operation to do this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your query but have a simiar question.

if obj.b and obj.b.field1 == 'something': 

the obj doesn't have a attribute "b"

elif obj.c and obj.c.field2

obj also doesn't have an attribute "c"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get to a child object from parent like you did in the final for loop, but you'd also need to check if the child exists for parent like so:

```
for obj in A.objects.all():
    try:
        if obj.b.field1 == 'something':
            do some operation
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # obj does not have a child of class B

    try:
        if obj.c.field2 == 5:
            do some other operation
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        # obj does not have a child of class C
```

You can also combine this into a single query using Q objects:

```
A.objects.filter(Q(b__isnull=False, b__field1='something') | Q(c__isnull=False, c__field2=5))
```

This would return objects of class A

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may be useful for someone. `hasattr` will return `True` for the correct child instance, `False` otherwise. Please note class name is in smallcase for `hasattr` parameter.

```
for obj in A.objects.all():
    if obj.hasattr('b'):
       # do something specific to b
    if obj.hasattr('c'):
       # do something specific to c
```